# custom search results affected by _REQUEST set

Tags: search

I am displaying search results in order of number of views or recency. To set the initial search results view to "views" I have this in my code:

```
if( !isset($_REQUEST['sorting'])) {
    $_REQUEST['sorting'] = "views";
}
```

However, if I include this code, then if there are no matches, it still displays all of the results for that category. If I remove this code, the search results display correctly. How can I set the default view without destroying the search results? And why does this code affect it??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine gave me this helpful answer, I hope it helps others:

"To answer definitively, I would need to see a bit more code. Nonetheless, WordPress does override $_REQUEST, so depending on where this code is placed, it may be overwritten. So assuming that the parameter is being passed in the URL, I would try:

```
if( !isset($_GET['sorting'])) { $_GET['sorting'] = "views"; }
```